# JQuery UI Drop Disable on selected elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i want to add drop limit on circles, i wrote a scrit for dragging circles

**the problem is user can drop circle on another circle, i don't want to allow it, 
simply i need to revert if the user drag and drop circle on another circle.**

i write some codes for this. but this not working for me, it always revert the dropped circle.
here is my example url

http://webxtreams.net/demoprofiles004/circledragger.html

here is js code i run on fire bug

```
$(".circle").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$(".circle").droppable({
    accept: function(el) {        
        return el.hasClass('.circle');
    }
});
```

please help me to do that.

have another little question -  can we track the reverting event on this, i need to repaint the lines when reverting the circle :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the draggable elements to recognize that they are being dropped on each other, you will need to implement some form of collision detection.  There are lots of resources online which explain the basic concepts of collision detection if you want to implement your own solution, or you can use a library which already implements it.

Here's an open-source library for Jquery that uses collision detection:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/

Comment: hmm i applied this, but not working for me, don't know what is the error